# Hibernate Search Filter not working with Tokenized field

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I am using Hibernate search 3.3 to search a Lucene index. I have a filter I need to use on a certain field, but also make it TOKENIZED for full text search. What I have found is that when I have the field set to UN_TOKENIZED, the filter works and full text search doesn't, and when I have it set to TOKENIZED, full text search works and the filter doesn't.

POJO

```
@Field(name = "owningOrganization", index = Index.UN_TOKENIZED, store = Store.YES)
@FieldBridge(impl = OrganizationNameFieldBridge.class)
public Organization getOwningOrganization()
{
```

Filter

```
@Factory
public Filter getFilter()
{
    BooleanQuery query = new BooleanQuery();
    Term orgTerm = new Term("owningOrganization", userOrganization);
    Term activeTerm = new Term("currentStateIsActive", "1");
    query.add(new TermQuery(orgTerm), Occur.SHOULD);
    query.add(new TermQuery(activeTerm), Occur.SHOULD);
    return new CachingWrapperFilter(new QueryWrapperFilter(query));
}
```

When I enter search terms of `owningOrganization:"This is the exact value of an organization"` I get no results, but the filter works as desired. And opposite when I switch it to TOKENIZED.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should index the field twice, once for searching (analyzed) and once for filtering. Per default using a *TermQuery* does not apply any analyzing. It searches the index for the term as specified.

```
@Fields({
   @Field(name = "owningOrganization_untokenized", index = Index.UN_TOKENIZED),
   @Field(name = "owningOrganization", index = Index.TOKENIZED, store = Store.YES
   }
)
public Organization getOwningOrganization(){
}
```

With this approach you have the owning organization field available tokenized and un-tokenized. You just have to use the right field name.